# PHP - Use preg_match_all multiple times

Tags: php, csv, preg-match-all

I'm working on a script that reads MAC adresses and locations from a CSV file. The thing is, I'm using preg_match_all two times. The first one is to find the MAC adress. The second one is based on the format in which the location is written. I know for a fact both the regular expressions work because I've switched them around.

I'm trying to get an output like this:
The Mac Adress **0c:85:25:c7:ab:f0** is located in **Tilburg-Compleet > P1 > P1-2e**

However, the output I'm receiving right now is:
The Mac Adress **0c:85:25:c7:ab:f0** is located in

Please help?

Kind regards, Brian

```
<?php
if (($handle = fopen("AP_Summary_20121004_104813_198.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    $num = count($data);
    for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) {

      $m = preg_match_all('~[0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}~', $data[$i], $match); 
      $c = preg_match_all('~^.{1,}\s\W\s.{1,}\s\W\s$~', $data[$i], $matches);

      if ($m) { 

        foreach ($match as $val){
          foreach ($matches as $values){
            echo 'The Mac Address <b>' . $val[0] . '</b> is located in <b>' . $values[0] . '</b><br /><br />';
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

Here's a short bit of the CSV file

```
EHV-R1-1e-109113   ,d8:24:bd:e9:ce:f0   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-1e        ,Enabled   
EHV-R1-1e-109117   ,d8:24:bd:e9:e6:40   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-1e   ,Enabled   
EHV-R1-1e-109118   ,d8:24:bd:e9:ed:b0   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-1e   ,Enabled   
Ehv-R1-2e-27088   ,00:12:44:ba:1e:00   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-2e   ,Enabled   
Ehv-R1-2e-27090   ,00:12:44:ba:1f:b0   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-2e   ,Enabled   
Ehv-R1-2e-27086   ,00:12:44:ba:20:c0   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-2e   ,Enabled   
Ehv-R1-2e-27087   ,00:12:44:ba:21:40   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-2e   ,Enabled   
Ehv-R1-2e-27084   ,00:12:44:ba:2b:10   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-2e   ,Enabled   
Ehv-R1-2e-27085   ,00:12:44:ba:32:a0   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-2e   ,Enabled   
Ehv-R1-2e-27094   ,00:12:44:ba:77:10   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-2e   ,Enabled   
Ehv-R1-2e-63664   ,00:1b:8f:89:28:c0   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-2e   ,Enabled   
Ehv-R1-2e-100264   ,00:3a:98:62:ae:a0   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-2e   ,Enabled   
Ehv-R1-2e-100266   ,00:3a:98:62:af:e0   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-2e   ,Enabled   
Ehv-R1-2e-100263   ,00:3a:98:72:b6:40   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-2e   ,Enabled   
Ehv-R1-2e-100265   ,00:3a:98:72:b9:f0   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-2e   ,Enabled   
Ehv-R1-2e-100261   ,00:3a:98:72:ba:f0   ,Eindhoven-rachelsemolen-TUE-TF > R1 > R1-2e   ,Enabled
```

Comment: You probably don't need 2 `foreach`s there. A sample of the CSV data would be nice.

Comment: Do you really need `preg_match_all()` for the MAC address? Are there really multiple MAC addresses in a single CSV column?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the Regexps are correct (which can't be told since you provided no example for the input), you might be able to get the result you wanted by using this:

```
if ($m) { 
    foreach ($match as $valKey => $val){
        echo 'The Mac Address <b>' . $val[0] . '</b> is located in <b>' . $matches[$valKey][0] . '</b><br /><br />';
    }
}
```

EDIT: But that's only true if the results are symmetrical. And, in that case (as Fabrício Matté pointed out), you should be able to get along with a single preg_match_all and capture the input you want with parenthesis, i.e.

```
preg_match_all('~([0-9])sometext([a-f])~', $data[$i], $match);
```

so `$match[1]` would give you whatever is in the `([0-9])` part and `$match[2]` would give you what is in the `([a-f])` part of the regexp.

EDIT2: Based on the data you provided, you should get along well with something like this:

```
preg_match('~^.*?([0-9a-f:]{17}).*?,(.*?),~i', $data[$i], $matches);
echo "MAC :".$matches[1];
echo "Location :".trim($matches[2]);
```

You get the idea, of course you can restrict the regexp more as you did, but the point is that you can get the parts of the regexp that match which are in parentheses in the `$matches` array with ascending index for the position of the group in parenthesis in your regexp from left to right.